# what's the difference between the source code of a page, and the data which firebug can see

Tags: screen-scraping, casperjs

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage and firebug shows the data I want to extract but it's not shown in the source code when I right click "show source code".

Is this because firebug shows the dynamic content which gets loaded by javascript etc?

Is phantomjs and casperjs the best way of extracting the contents of this page, including all the div elements. I need to extract the data shown by firebug.

Does casper js have a casper.GrabHTML method, like mechanize and beautifulsoup? which will get all of the dom elements, like clsses, hrefs , links, buttons, text etc

Comment: Yes, see casper methods : `getHTML()`, `debugHTML()`, `getPageContent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the order in which stuff happens:**

PHP generates HTML
Browser loads HTML
JavaScript manipulate loaded HTML

**Why is this?**

The view source browser feature normally shows the plain HTML as received by the browser. Other advanced tools like Firefug are able to display the current HTML after being changed by JavaScript. (Firefox itself has this feature as well: just right click on some generated HTML and choose "View selected source".)

**How can I access the full (firebug html)?**

I'm not sure about the HTML tab but the Network tab always displays documents as received from the server.

**Can I do it in php/javascript?**

PHP is no longer running when the original HTML reaches the browser.

JavaScript can display HTML with the `.innerHTML` property of any DOM node.

Comment: can you select inner html based on the Xpath? Where does Xpath fit into this equation. Of the beginner videos I have seen for casperjs people just call a function which loads some xpath to select an element like a button or link to click on.

Comment: node() = innerXml

text() = innerText
both are arrays, so text()[1] is a first children text node...

Comment: In addition to javascript manipulating the dom, FF will also usually alter it to make it more html5 compliant.